# Are there any specific processor instructions missing from "non-compatible" Windows 11 CPUs that could crash Windows 11 running on them in future?

Tags: hyper-v, compatibility, windows-11, hypervisor, assembly

I'm aware of:

- the official supported CPU list
- the requirement for TPM 2.0
- the requirement for Secure Boot

As I'm sure several will know, the above requirements can be bypassed to get Windows 11 running on officially "non-compatible" hardware.

**additional instructions in the instruction set of newer processors?**

But for the CPUs in that supported list, do they have additional instructions in their instruction set that could be used by Microsoft developers in future Windows 11 versions?

I am wondering if such instructions could appear in the low level assembly code in some parts of Windows, or be generated in the machine language elsewhere in the software by the C/C++ compilers used. If this was the case, then the prospect of extending the useful life* of non-compatible hardware in running Windows 11 is eventually going to abruptly end once an update comes out that contains code with these processor instructions: processors that don't have them will not recognise them and the software would have a likelihood of failing, be unreliable or insecure.

If these new processors do not introduce new processor instructions then the prospect for existing "non-compatible" hardware is more optimistic. The challenge then might still be to stub dependency on hardware peripherals like TPM 2.0 and also installation environment such as SecureBoot.

**x86-64 is always x86-64?**

Apart from the distinction between x86 32bit amd x84-64 or amd64 64bit instruction sets (the latter only supported by Windows 11) I'm not aware of any other variants that the new processors would only support.

**Virtualisation to the rescue?**

Should such addition instructions exist in the compatible processors, that may be used in Windows 11 in the future, the other option for "non-compatible" hardware could be a virtualisation layer (provided by an established 3rd party vendor in this line, perhaps) that translates on the fly the new instructions into something that the older CPUs can support, while most other instructions supported by the older CPU just pass through, so overall the performance is similar to fully native. We see such virtualisation and translation in several cases: x86-64 apps emulated on Windows on ARM, Apple Rosetta running on M1 to support Apple Intel compiled apps.

**User experience - making the virtualisation seamless, like the machine has a newer CPU from boot**

The challenge for a maker of such virtualisation to ensure Windows 11 to run on older hardware could be I think the user experience. Ideally it should be present after booting, so that Windows 11 runs from boot on the virtualisation. Rather this, than booting to Windows 10, then running a Virtualisation application (like VirtualBox, VMware or Parallels to boot a Windows 11 image). That's extra steps, clunky and may not be as performance. So to my mind Hypervisor software could be the approach to running Windows 11 from the beginning at boot on older hardware. Would welcome thoughts here too.

**Of course, Linux**

*before anyone mentions it, I am well aware of Linux and the various distributions that will may well still run on such "older" "non-compatible" hardware. Aware, because I use Linux every day, along with Windows and macOS. I'm not here for an idealogical discussion on what platform is better than another, sorry.

Comment: I very much doubt its a change to the Instruction set, and if its related specifically to instructions it will be with the actual implementation of the affected instructions (there won't be more or fewer of them, and they will have the same names; they will just work differently). this article is guessing MS is saying 8th Gen and up, because of the spectre/meltdown mitigations are in hardware, and won't cause the huge performance hit that accompanied the software and microcode patches required to quell the vulnerability: https://www.howtogeek.com/739029/why-doesnt-windows-11-support-my-cpu/

Comment: Software would have to be written to not your not not check if the processor supports an instruction but ignore the error caused by running said instruction. The list of instructions supported by 8th core (and AMD equivalent) and any processor that supports fTPM (consider this the bare minimum to run Windows 11) is identical.  However, newer processors, have security features that the older processors don’t have which Windows 11 will take advantage of. There is one specific instruction set that is being patched out by Intel AVX-512 but that’s only for 12th Gen

Comment: also consider, "compatibility" may have a more nuanced meaning than just "it works" (or "it doesn't"). If Microsoft set design goals that can't be achieved with an older chip, even if the software will work perfectly fine without it, that can still be called "incompatible".

Comment: +1 thank you @Frank Thomas with regard to mentioning spectre. On that situation, the change to address it would be no new functionality, but rather to patch a security vulnerability. My assumption here that there would be no legitimate software that would make use of the 'unofficial' vulnerability. As you say, the performance of applications software would improve. But one could say that with Windows 11 assuming the hardware is fixed, then the software patches in windows to mitigate in Windows 10 if they were there, would not be in W11 so it would less secure on older hardware.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Ramhound with regard to the AVX-512 in 12th gen - are there lower gen CPUs i.e. 11th and lower in the W11 compatibility list. I would suppose that the virtualisation concept I mentioned to do on the fly translation might help here.

Comment: is there are versioning convention for x86-64 so we can tell if new instructions might be present?

Comment: @FrankThomas with regard to nuanced compatibility, that's intriguing thank you,  do you have any examples?

Comment: well, one example would be secureboot. MS initially told OEMs that they could only call their devices compatible with win10 if the system shipped with SecureBoot enabled.  Win10 works perfectly fine with secureboot turned off, so its technology is compatible, but OEMs were legally bound to enable it if they refer to a model as Win10 compatible. https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/03/windows-10-to-make-the-secure-boot-alt-os-lock-out-a-reality/

Comment: I have W11 on several pre Intel i series computers absolutely with no issues, these  hardware requirements just help sell new PC's imho.

Comment: @therobyouknow - It’s trivial to use compiler directives to test for compatibility of a specific instruction

Comment: @Moab - While some of it might be to help sell new hardware.  Intel and AMD both are stopping support for Legacy Mode in their new processors.  Both have hardware video decoders with some support for DRM (like Netflix uses) and other specific hardware.  So can Windows 11 run on older hardware, sure, but Microsoft doesn’t want to worry about incompatibility with that hardware.  I also suspect very quickly Software will take advantage of those new processor compatibles since Microsoft will make it extremely easy to do so. I have heard Intel and AMD longer wanted to support compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question and based on comment contributions (thank you), I would be inclined to conclude:

**Answer**

At the moment, the answer appears to range between:

1. No. No specific instructions in the Windows 11 supported CPU list used by Windows 11 executables that aren't in those not in that list
2. No. *It's not known* that there are specific instructions in the Windows 11 supported CPU list used by Windows 11 executables that aren't in those not in that list
3. No. But *apps* specifically for Windows 11 may make use of instructions in these supported CPUs and therefore not run on a Windows 11 machine with a non-supported processor. The workaround here would be not to use Windows Store programs, but their independent download equivalent, if the vendor also supports that and use the Compatibility Mode facility to run the app within an earlier version of Windows. The assumed outcome here is that alterate executables are run and/or conditionals within the code select code compatible with all CPUs that run on the earlier version of Windows selected.

Naturally I'd like it to be '1'. Assuming that [the definition of x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#x86-64) still holds and that Windows 11 runs on that same definition of x86-64 hardware.

But that might beg a refined question: What is the precise criteria for a CPU to be supported by Windows 11? If it's not x86-64 then what is it? (which I may ask as a separate question).

Further possible questions can include: how does Windows 11 detect the supported CPU model?